# Multi GPU architecture, gradient averaging - less accurate model?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

When I execute the cifar10 model as described at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn I achieve 86% accuracy after approx 4 hours using a single GPU , when I utilize 2 GPU's the accuracy drops to 84% but reaching 84% accuracy is faster on 2 GPU's than 1.

My intuition is 
that average_gradients function as defined at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py returns a less accurate gradient value as an average of gradients will be less accurate than the actual gradient value.

If the gradients are less accurate then the parameters than control the function that is learned as part of training is less accurate. Looking at the code (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py) why is averaging the gradients over multiple GPU's less accurate than computing the gradient on a single GPU ?

Is my intuition of averaging the gradients producing a less accurate value correct ?

Randomness in the model is described as :

```
The images are processed as follows:
They are cropped to 24 x 24 pixels, centrally for evaluation or randomly for training.
They are approximately whitened to make the model insensitive to dynamic range.
For training, we additionally apply a series of random distortions to artificially increase the data set size:

Randomly flip the image from left to right.
Randomly distort the image brightness.
Randomly distort the image contrast.
```

src : https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn

Does this have an effect on training accuracy ?

Update :

Attempting to investigate this further, the loss function value training with different number of GPU's.

```
Training with 1 GPU : loss value : .7 , Accuracy : 86%
Training with 2 GPU's : loss value : .5 , Accuracy : 84%
```

Shouldn't the loss value be lower for higher for higher accuracy, not vice versa ?

Comment: What loss function are you using? And how are you calculating your accuracy?

Comment: @Engineero To calculate accuracy I use cifar10_eval.py as specified at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn . Loss function is tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits as specified on line 288 at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you linked, using the function `average_gradient` with 2 GPUs is **exactly equivalent** (1) to simply using 1 GPU with **twice the batch size**.

You can see it in the definition:

```
grad = tf.concat(axis=0, values=grads)
grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)
```

Using a larger batch size (given the same number of epochs) can have any kind of effect on your results.

Therefore, if you want to do exactly equivalent (1) calculations in 1-GPU or 2-GPU cases, you may want to **halve** the batch size in the latter case. (People sometimes avoid doing it, because smaller batch sizes may also make the computation on each GPU slower, in some cases)

Additionally, one needs to be careful with learning rate decay here. If you use it, you want to make sure the learning rate is the same in the `n`th epoch in both 1-GPU and 2-GPU cases -- I'm not entirely sure this code is doing the right thing here. I tend to print the learning rate in the logs, something like

```
print sess.run(lr)
```

should work here.

(1) Ignoring issues related to pseudo-random numbers, finite precision or data set sizes not divisible by the batch size.

Answer (score 5):

There is a decent discussion of this [here](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#parallelizinganddistributingsgd) (not my content). Basically when you distribute SGD, you have to communicate gradients back and forth somehow between workers. This is inherently imperfect, and so your distributed SGD typically diverges from a sequential, single-worker SGD at least to some degree. It is also typically faster, so there is a trade off.

[[Zhang *et. al.*, 2015]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6651.pdf) proposes one method for distributed SGD called elastic-averaged SGD. The paper goes through a stability analysis characterizing the behavior of the gradients under different communication constraints. It gets a little heavy, but it might shed some light on why you see this behavior.

**Edit:** regarding whether the loss should be lower for the higher accuracy, it is going to depend on a couple of things. First, I am assuming that you are using softmax cross-entropy for your loss (as stated in the deep_cnn tutorial you linked), and assuming accuracy is the total number of correct predictions divided by the total number of samples. In this case, a lower loss *on the same dataset* should correlate to a higher accuracy. The emphasis is important.

If you are reporting loss during training but then report accuracy on your validation (or testing) dataset, it is possible for these two to be only loosely correlated. This is because the model is fitting (minimizing loss) to a certain subset of your total samples throughout the training process, and then tests against new samples that it has never seen before to verify that it generalizes well. The loss against this testing/validation set could be (and probably is) higher than the loss against the training set, so if the two numbers are being reported from different sets, you may not be able to draw comparisons like "loss for 1 GPU case should be lower since its accuracy is lower".

Second, if you are distributing the training then you are calculating losses across multiple workers (I believe), but only one accuracy at the end, again against a testing or validation set. Maybe the loss being reported is the best loss seen by any one worker, but overall the average losses were higher.

Basically I do not think we have enough information to decisively say why the loss and accuracy do not seem to correlate the way you expect, but there are a number of ways this could be happening, so I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: please see question update : 'Shouldn't the loss value be lower for higher for higher accuracy, not vice versa ?'

Comment: "This is inherently imperfect" can you elaborate on this? Is this a good anology ? : Think of each gradient as a slope of line then averaging each slope does not give true slope but close appproximation

Comment: I think that really depends on the specific implementation. In one case maybe every worker is working on a different subset of your training set, so the gradient for any mini-batch for one worker might be different from the same iteration for another worker. You have to merge these together somehow, so you end up with probably an averaged gradient. Another case might be that your network parameters update before receiving a gradient from a worker, and then update again based on a gradient that was calculated for the old parameters. Basically I think it depends on your method.

Comment: The discussion provided in the first link of the answer is regarding communication problems in different **asynchronous** SGD parallelizations. However the distributed cifar10 model from the question is  completely synchronous and thereby slower, but not affected by the communication problems described above. Also, due to the synchronous updates, every worker uses the same parameters at every learning step. Therefore the loss and accuracy will not be different across the workers.

Answer (score 3):

I've also encountered this issue.
See [Accurate, Large Minibatch SGD: Training ImageNet in 1 Hour](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02677) from Facebook which addresses the same issue. The suggested solution is simply to scale up the learning rate by k (after some reasonable warm-up epochs) for k GPUs.

In practice I've found out that simply summing up the gradients from the GPUs (rather than averaging them) and using the original learning rate sometimes does the job as well.